# How does the PRELOAD (and other) constants/symbols work in Test2::API::Instance?

Tags: perl, constants, symbols

Where are [these symbols defined in `Test2::API::Instance`](https://metacpan.org/release/Test-Simple/source/lib/Test2/API/Instance.pm#L151)

```
sub _finalize {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($caller) = @_;
    $caller ||= [caller(1)];

    confess "Attempt to initialize Test2::API during preload"
        if $self->{+PRELOAD};

    $self->{+FINALIZED} = $caller;

    $self->{+_PID} = $$        unless defined $self->{+_PID};
    $self->{+_TID} = get_tid() unless defined $self->{+_TID};
```

I see a constant `+PRELOAD`, `+FINALIZED`, `+_PID`, and `+_TID`. How are these even specified, when I try to find them `rg PRELOAD /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/` I see nothing.

Comment: It's based on https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::HashBase. I haven't got time to read the code, but https://metacpan.org/source/Test2::Util::HashBase#L12 gave it away.